# Linearly distributive categories: Principles of excluded middle and contradiction

Tags: logic, category-theory, tensor-products, monoidal-categories, linear-logic

**1. Context**
Let $(\mathscr{C}, \otimes, \top, \oplus, \bot, \delta ^l, \delta^r)$ be a [linearly distributive category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/linearly+distributive+category).
Let $(S,S', \alpha, \beta, \alpha‘, \beta‘)$ be a negation on $\mathscr{C}$. This data consists of:

> - Two contravariant functors $S: \mathscr{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mathscr{C}$ and $S': \mathscr{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mathscr{C}$
> - For any $A \in \mathscr{C}$ four morphisms:
>   $$\alpha: SA \otimes A \rightarrow \bot \\
>   \alpha': A \otimes S'A \rightarrow \bot \\
>   \beta: \top \rightarrow A \oplus SA \\
>   \beta': \top \rightarrow S'A \oplus A$$
>   satisfying certain [coherence diagrams](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/linear/Cockett-Seely-WDC-Durham1991-corrected.pdf).

Interpreting $\otimes$ as conjunction, $\oplus$ as disjunction, $\bot$ as falsity, $\top$ as truth and $\rightarrow$ as implication the morphisms $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ are reminiscent of the principle of contradiction while $\beta$ and $\beta'$ look like tertium non datur.

**2. Questions**

- Can this observation be given mathematical meaning? Can it be made precise?
- If so, how do the coherence diagrams for $\alpha$ , $\alpha'$, $\beta$ , $\beta'$ relate to the law of excluded middle and the principle of contradiction?

I suppose this question arises from my (still remaining) lack of understanding of the [connection between linear logic and linearly distributive categories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421193/linear-logic-and-linearly-distributive-categories).